# I am having troubles importing a button from React bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import a button from a react-bootstrap from a button group but I'm having issues. I would like to make this into a jumbotron with a title and a button that links to another page.

```
    import Jumbotron from "react-bootstrap/Jumbotron";
    import ButtonGroup from "react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup";

    export default class Jumpotron extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <>
    <Jumbotron fluid>
    <h1 className="header">Welcome to Zach's page</h1>
    </Jumbotron>

    <ButtonGroup aria-label="Basic example">
      <Button variant="secondary">Left</Button>
      <Button variant="secondary">Middle</Button>
      <Button variant="secondary">Right</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
    </>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: [`import { Button, ButtonGroup } from 'reactstrap';`](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/button-group/)

Comment: That basically fixes my problem but it still won't export my component.

Comment: I forgot to include import React from "react";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include import React from "react" and put brackets around Button and Button Group.

```
import React from "react";
import Jumbotron from "react-bootstrap/Jumbotron";
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from "react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup";

export default class Jumpotron extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
<Jumbotron fluid>
<h1 className="header">Welcome to Zach's page</h1>
</Jumbotron>

<ButtonGroup aria-label="Basic example">
  <Button variant="secondary">Left</Button>
  <Button variant="secondary">Middle</Button>
  <Button variant="secondary">Right</Button>
</ButtonGroup>
</>
    );
  }
}
```